How to correctly include an Eclipse PlugIn Project in Eclipse Committers?
I wrote a PlugIn Project in Eclipse which should Resolve Variables in a custom way.
The idea came for faster implementaion of getter/setter methods:
public ${type} get${varNameUpper}(${type}${varNameLower}){
    return ${varNameLower};
}

This template should take the "varNameUpper/Lower" Variable and adjust it simultaneously. For this I wrote the PlugIn-Classes:
public class Lower extends SimpleTemplateVariableResolver {
    
    public Lower() {
        super("varNameLower", "Converts first letter to lower");
    }
    
    @Override
    protected String resolve(TemplateContext context) {
        String variableName = context.getVariable("variableName");
        if (variableName != null && !variableName.isEmpty()) {
            return variableName.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase() + variableName.substring(1);
        }
        
        return "";
    }

And
public class Context extends TemplateContextType {

    public Context() {
        super("de.s231371.plugin.context");
        
        // Register variable resolvers
        addResolver(new Lower());
        addResolver(new Upper());
    }
}

The issue is, that I am able to include the PlugIn into Eclipse so that Eclipse lists it under "Installed Software", but in the Template Section where I can set the context for my Template Resolver it is not listet.
I exported it as .jar File and added it to the eclipse/dropins folder, which at least seems to integrate it into eclipse.
My Manifest and Plugin.xml:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Automatic-Module-Name: de.s231371.plugin
Bundle-Name: templateHandler
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Bundle-SymbolicName: de.s231371.plugin;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.1.1
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.jface.text;bundle-version="3.25.0"


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin>
   <!-- Template Context Registration -->
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.editors.templates">
      <contextType
            class="de.s231371.plugin.Context"
            id="de.s231371.plugin.context"
            name="Custom Plugin Template Context">
      </contextType>
      <!-- Template Definition -->
      <template
         id="de.s231371.plugin.template"
         name="Custom Template"
         contextTypeId="de.s231371.plugin.context"
         description="A custom template for demonstration purposes">
         <pattern>
            <![CDATA[
            public ${type} get${varNameUpper}(${type} ${varNameLower}) {
               return ${varNameLower};
            }
            public void set${varNameUpper}(${type} ${varNameLower}) {
               this.${varNameLower} = ${varNameLower};
            }
            ]]>
         </pattern>
      </template>
   </extension>
</plugin>

I also tried to launch the PlugIn directly in DebugMode, which again includes it in Eclipse, but doesn't list it in the TemplateContext-Menue.

Where exactly are you looking for this? I don't know what you mean by "TemplateContext-Menu"

You've declared a template context, but I don't see anything about adding that context to any existing UIs, nor anything about your own UI being added that would show it. It looks like you want to operate on Java sources and add a variable resolver of your own, in which case you need to contribute to an existing Java context. If every context showed up everywhere, you'd have contexts for XML, SQL, and other languages in contexts where only Java templates make sense.

I am looking for it under Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Templates->New...->Context: That is a context dropdown menue and I've been told by my teacher that my Plugin should integrate right into this context menue, so that eclipse knows how it should resolve the variabletags like ${varNameUpper} and so on

@nitind can you maybe tell me how to add it to an existing context? I am not too familliar with java and eclipse

You are probably going to have to look at the plugin.xml of the org.eclipse.jdt.ui plug-in to see what context types it defines. If you are not familiar with Java and Eclipse this seems like a very tough assignment

Yes I am not feeling all so well with it...nevertheless I have to submit it on Monday :(

https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_editors_templates.html?cp=2_1_1_157 has the reference doc for the extension point. Coupled with the context IDs in the jdt.ui plug-in as mentioned, you'll be able to register a variable resolver and add templates. If this is something you have to submit (?), they'll need to understand you can't change that UI that way--the CodeTemplateBlock class doesn't allow for it. I'm also very curious what sort of training includes Eclipse IDE extensions; seems like it would be very rare.

Okay thanks, I'll try to get some insights from the link :)
